# Most efficient way to retrieve text to populate UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to make an app that gets updated, so for this I think I will use a website where I'll input text and I want to read the website with the app and populate an array to make a TableView. I Even thought of making it a struct array, where the structure has the Title, description, etc. and populate the tableview with this, and when I want to update the content in the app just read the text and with that fill the tableview. for example:

```
*
Title
Date
description
*
Title
date
description
```

give this format to the website and translate each * into a struct and into a tableview cell

I really don't know if this is the most effective way of doing it. Or what would be the best way to do this app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at returning json from your web site.  You might find that consistent and structured data is easier to manage in the future than something arbitrary.

[This tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/fetch-parse-json-ios-programming-tutorial/) will help you achieve what you're looking for.

Comment: would json also help retrieve an image from the website or what is the best way to retrieve an image and add it to the app?

Comment: json could return the URL and then you could download the image separately.

Comment: Thanks! this perfectly solves my doubts and problems!

Comment: I've been trying to work this out but I cant figure it out. How do I set up the server/website end for this?

Answer (score 0):

I would go for some existing free web services that can act as your backend. For example stackmob.com provides free backend with unlimited requests and is also very easy to deploy with their SDK.

If you have a hosting, then perhaps wordpress with WordPress API plugin can also serve as your free web service and you will also have all the powers of wordpress content management and flexibility for expansion.